# I want the update query for hook alter form for my created custom field

Tags: php, drupal

```
  Alter form in my account page i written:

  $form['field_first_name']['und']['0']['value']['#value'] = 'raju';

  function my_callback_function($form,$form_state)
   {
   global $user;
    $var = db_update('field_data_field_name')
     ->fields(array(
       'field_name_value' => $form_state['value']['field_name[und][0][value]'],  - > Not working -> store as NULL
       'field_name_value' => '', -> empty value
       'field_name_value' => 'raju', -> hard code stored
       ))
     ->condition('entity_id', $user->uid, '=')
     ->condition('entity_type', 'user', '=')
     ->execute();
     drupal_set_message('Updated sifhup');
     }
```

Default value is only storing in Database from API i fixed. But i like to override the value whenever need. So i want to know the form_state values from field in the database.

[image: Doubt]

Answer (score 0):

A recommendation, install [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) and use `dsm($form_state['values']);` then inspect the array to find the correct array key.

Comment: i installed the Devel and dpm[$form] is working. when i use dsm it through the undefined index. Could u suggest me example

Comment: Have to call it in your callback function. if it says $form_state is undefined it looks somethink is wrong with your code. Where and how do you add your callback?

Comment: i tried in callback function but i could not able to get the result. Any example will be guide full for me.

Comment: I manual change the form alter field name, like normal writing of custom module. i changed ($form['field_first_name']['und']['0']['value'])  name field to ($form_state['values']['field_first_name']). By now it works